# Express multer middleware blocks request on data execution

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, multer

I need to get the request progress AS a file is uploaded.

If I do

```js
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req,res,next) => {
  req.on('data', ()=> {
    //DO SOMETHING
  )
  //PROCESS MY FILE
})
```

**LOCALLY AND ON AWS EC2:**

the "DO SOMETHING" method is only executed AFTER the multer middleware has done receiving all the file, so it doesn't work

---

So what I'm doing instead is:

```js
app.post('/upload', (req,res,next) => {
  req.on('data', ()=> {
    //DO SOMETHING
  )
  next()

}, upload.single('file'), (req, res, next) => {
  //PROCESS MY FILE
})
```

**LOCALLY:**

This works and "DO SOMETHING" is called whenever a chunk of file is uploaded

**ON AWS EC2**

This is not working. All the "DO SOMETHING" are called at the same time after the multer middleware is done receiving the file.

***Why is it behaving this way?***

***How do I get it to correctly fire the events?***

---

PS: I tried placing the `next()` call inside the data event once the file upload has completed, but then multer throws an exception

`Error: Unexpected end of form at Multipart._final`